# Artist.findOne is not a function

Tags: mongoose, electron, mongoose-schema, mongoose-models

I am getting the error inside my Electron application when I run this code inside my `FindArtist.js` file:

```
const Artist = require('../models/artist');

/**
 * Finds a single artist in the artist collection.
 * @param {string} _id - The ID of the record to find.
 * @return {promise} A promise that resolves with the Artist that matches the id
 */
module.exports = _id => {
  return Artist.findOne({ _id: _id });
};
```

I definitely installed mongoose, but it seems I am no longer importing mongoose or the Artist model appropriately? Not sure.

Here is the `models/artist.js` file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const AlbumSchema = require('./album');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ArtistSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  age: Number,
  yearsActive: Number,
  image: String,
  genre: String,
  website: String,
  netWorth: Number,
  labelName: String,
  retired: Boolean,
  albums: [AlbumSchema]
});

const Artist = mongoose.model('artist', ArtistSchema);

module.exports = ArtistSchema;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out that my `module.exports` on my `models/artist.js` file was wrong.

Instead of:

```
// const Artist = mongoose.model('artist', ArtistSchema);

// module.exports = ArtistSchema;
```

it should be this:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('artist', ArtistSchema);
```